# Is it possible to display the real device like the emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a real device and I connect it with android studio . Is it possible to display the screen like an emulated device inside android studio, in order to work remotely with it?

Answer (score 1):

yes maybe it is possible to use a real device as an emulator
try this reference link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nN9USg7mHCk

Comment: @maria, If this answer is useful for you then, please mark an answer as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no, as basic Android Studio testing like this is assumed binary (i.e. either you're testing on the emulator or a virtual device).

You could go into the Emulator settings and create a new 'virtual device' that exactly matches the phone you're connecting, with the right operating system, and that's as close as you're going to get AFAIK.